# In Github action authenticate docker through workload identity GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions, workload-identity

I was able to authenticate GHA through Workload Identity federation (WIF) successfully

```
steps:
  - name: git checkout
    uses: actions/checkout@v3

  - id: auth
    name: Authenticate to Google Cloud with Federation
    uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v1'
    with:
      workload_identity_provider: 'projects/11111/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/gha-identity-pool-2/providers/gha-identity-pool-provider'
      service_account: 'gha-sv-account@project1.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
```

But when I try to run docker compose service which needs GCP authentication, I get error:

```
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('Unable to acquire impersonated credentials: 
No access token or invalid expiration in response.', 
'{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 403,\n    
"message": "Permission \'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken\' 
denied on resource (or it may not exist).",\n    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
\n    "details": [\n      {\n        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",\n        
"reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",\n        
"domain": "iam.googleapis.com",\n        
"metadata": {\n          "permission": "iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken"\n        }\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}\n')
```

**WIF cred file format:**

```
{
    "type": "external_account",
    "audience": "//iam.google.apis.com/projects/PROJECT_NUMBER

/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/cloudrun-oidc-pool/subject/USER_EMAIL

",
    "subject_token_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:jwt",
    "token_url": "https://sts.googleapis.com/v1/token",
    "credential_source": {
        "file" "token.txt" }
}
```

**sv account key cred file format**

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "abc",
  "private_key_id": "9b173d1620d4fdf9d348d74a9d33848b39b3f117",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----aoisjd\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "x@y.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "29384u23",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/yx",
  "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
}
```

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: ${{steps.auth.outputs.credentials_file_path}}
```

This works with service account key authentication. doesnt work with WIF. Because both cred files have different format

My sv account has `serviceAccountTokenCreator` role. I also tried giving it `owner` role just to see if lack of role was the issue, but even then I received same error.

**Terraform code to create WIF:**

```
resource "google_iam_workload_identity_pool" "gha-identity-pool" {
  workload_identity_pool_id = "gha-identity-pool-2"
}


resource "google_iam_workload_identity_pool_provider" "gha-identity-pool-provider" {
  workload_identity_pool_id          = google_iam_workload_identity_pool.gha-identity-pool.workload_identity_pool_id
  workload_identity_pool_provider_id = "gha-identity-pool-provider"
  display_name                       = "GHA identity pool provider"
  attribute_mapping                  = {
    "google.subject"       = "assertion.sub"
    "attribute.actor"      = "assertion.actor"
    "attribute.repository" = "assertion.repository"
  }
  oidc {
    issuer_uri = "https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
  }
}

data "google_project" "gcp_project" {}


resource "google_service_account_iam_member" "gha-sv-account-wif-iam-member" {
  service_account_id = var.gha_service_account_name
  role               = "roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser"
  member             = "principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/projects/${data.google_project.gcp_project.number}/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/${google_iam_workload_identity_pool.gha-identity-pool.workload_identity_pool_id}/attribute.repository/org1/repo1"
}


resource "google_service_account_iam_member" "gha-sv-account-wif-tokencreator-iam-member" {
  service_account_id = var.gha_service_account_name
  role               = "roles/owner"
  member             = "principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/projects/${data.google_project.gcp_project.number}/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/${google_iam_workload_identity_pool.gha-identity-pool.workload_identity_pool_id}/attribute.repository/org1/repo1"
}
resource "google_project_iam_member" "wif-owner-iam" {
  project = var.project_id
  role    = "roles/owner"
  member  = "principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/projects/${data.google_project.gcp_project.number}/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/${google_iam_workload_identity_pool.gha-identity-pool.workload_identity_pool_id}/attribute.repository/org1/repo1"
}
```

Comment: You are probably graning `serviceAccountTokenCreator` on the wrong resource (service account). The service account that is being impersonated (identity A) grants permission to the other identity (identity B). That means modifying the IAM policy bindings of identity A to grant the other service account (identity B) `serviceAccountTokenCreator`.

Comment: `Because both cred files have different format`. That makes no difference. The credential format has nothing to do with permissions. The error message is telling you that the permission `iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken` has not been granted. If you have added `Owner` to an identity and that did not work, that means you added the permission to/for the **wrong** identity.

Comment: I tried adding owner to WIF pool too. getting same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For authenticating GHA through WIF - use the same GHA code as mentioned in the question.
In GHA copy credential file to a location that can be used by docker container.
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76956314/3842788) - how to create WIF through terraform for particular github repository.

The error I was having in above question was related to my terraform code. I was using wrong repository name.

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve your issue, you can try the below suggested points and let me know.

- Seems to be you are having issues with service token creation. To
  create or access a Token you need to grant the permission to
  impersonation service account `iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken` and
  [Service Account Token Creator role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-permissions#directly-impersonate) . Try adding above permissions and
  have a try .
- Make sure you have the `IAM Service Account Credentials API`, API
  enabled in your GCP project first, which then enables the creation of
  short-lived tokens for service account impersonations.
- As John Hanley suggested, make sure to add the required permission to
  correct workload identity. To allow external identities to
  impersonate a service account, you grant them the Workload Identity
  User role (`roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser`) on the service account.
  You can grant the role to a specific external identity, or to
  multiple external identities. For more configuration options, see the
  [Workload Identity Federation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/configuring-workload-identity-federation#github-actions) documentation. As you are using
  Terraform to automate your infrastructure provisioning, check out the
  [GitHub OIDC Terraform module](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-github-actions-runners/tree/master/modules/gh-oidc) too.

Comment: Would you be able to show how its done through terraform ?

Comment: Can you refer to this [GCP Service Account impersonation with Terraform](https://devcoops.com/terraform-gcp-service-account-impersonation/#google_vignette) and [Using Google Cloud Service Account impersonation in your Terraform code](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/using-google-cloud-service-account-impersonation-your-terraform-code) by Roger Martinez

Comment: How to grant serviceAccountTokenCreator to identity pool through TF ? 
FOllowing doesnt work :       
``` resource "google_service_account_iam_member" "gha-sv-account-wif-tokencreator-iam-member" {
  service_account_id = var.gha_service_account_name
  role               = "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator"
  member             = "principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/projects/${data.google_project.gcp_project.number}/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/${google_iam_workload_identity_pool.gha-identity-pool.workload_identity_pool_id}/attribute.repository/org1/repo1
} ```

Comment: @Aseem : Find this [Impersonating Service Accounts](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference.html#impersonating-service-accounts) in terraform doc